# How to connect to vault with github token?

Tags: spring-cloud-vault-config

Our Vault is configured to use github tokens.  How can one use spring-cloud-vault and use github tokens?  looked all over documentation and forums.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "spring-cloud-vault" is the same as Hashicorp Vault (and according to https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/ this looks pretty much the same!), you first need make sure the "github" auth method is enabled.

> Our Vault is configured to use github tokens

So this seems to be the case already.

Next you need to create a GitHub personal token on https://github.com/settings/tokens. Click on "Generate new token" and in the "admin:org" scope, select "read:org", then generate the token and copy it. 
See this GitHub guide for additional help: https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

You will get a token code. With this you can log in to your Vault. In the Vault UI select "GitHub" as Method, then paste the copied token.

If you are using the Vault API, e.g. with `curl`, you need to add the token as a HTTP header:

```
$ curl -X POST \
--data '{"token": "YOURSECRETANDPERSONALGITHUBTOKEN" }' https://vault.example.com/v1/auth/github/login
```

Note that in this example Vault is behind a reverse proxy, therefore not using the port 8200 in the URL.

You should get a HTTP 200 and a json reponse when you successfully logged in. 
See https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/github.html for more details.